# How to find net loss or gain on the sale of all the particles

Tags: percentages

A man sells three articles A, B, C and gains 10% on A, 20% on B and loses 10% on C. **He breaks even when combined selling prices of A and C are considered**, whereas he gains 5% when combined selling prices of B and C are considered. What is his net loss or gain on the sale of all the articles?

I cannot understand the bold written part. Calculating for the gain of 5% when combined selling prices of B and C are considered, I get that the prices(actual) of B and C are same. But with this I can't find the net loss or gain on the sale of all the particles.

Need some help please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the costs of $A$, $B$ and $C$ respectively. Then the selling prices are $1.1a$, $1.2b$ and $0.9c$ respectively. So we have

$$1.1a+0.9c=a+c$$

and

$$1.2b+0.9c=1.05(b+c)$$

So we can express $b$ and $c$ in terms of $a$.

The percentage gain on the sale of all the articles is

$$\frac{0.1a+0.2b-0.1c}{a+b+c}\times 100\%$$

Comment: I think the original prices have to be subtracted first before we can find the percentage gain. Also, the name percentage **change** will be more suitable unless we are sure that it is gain.

Comment: @Mick My mistake. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: so the meaning of 'he breaks even when...' is the selling prices and total costs are equal?@CYAries

Comment: @mathiu_lady It should be. No gain, no loss

Comment: @CYAries Why in the second equation  you have taken 1.05(b+c) in the r.h.s.? Here it is given 5% gain so it comes like .05(b+c)

Comment: The cost is $b+c$ and the gain is $0.05(b+c)$. So the selling price should be $1.05(b+c)$.

Comment: $a=b=c $ and the answer is $6.66\%$